# Show that: $\lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{k=1}^n \cos(k\sqrt{\frac{3}{n^3}} t) = e^{- \frac{t^2}{2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, infinite-product

Is it true that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{k=1}^n  \cos\left(k\sqrt{\frac{3}{n^3}} t\right) = e^{- \frac{t^2}{2}}$$ ? How to proceed ?

Comment: This definitely could use some more context.

Comment: @AdamHughes: What do you mean ?

Comment: I mean, where did this question come from, why do you expect it is true, and possibly what have you tried on the matter.